# overriding __getattr__ on model breaks django-model-utils InheritanceManager

Tags: python, django

I am using django-model-utils package and I am trying to override **getattr** on a model for which i am also defining a InheritanceManager on.

I have multiple models inheriting from this same model and i am calling .select_subclasses() on the parent model to get a queryset of child models.

The problem is that the InheritanceManager is doing a try/except on ObjectDoesNotExist exception while my **getattr** raises a AttributeError exception (which is the standard).  This causes the queryset to fail since the AttributeError is not caught by the InheritanceManager.

Any ideas on how i can resolve this.  I don't think i want to raise ObjectDoesNotExist in my **getattr** method.. but am not sure what else to try.

Thanks!

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from model_utils.managers import InheritanceManager


class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')

    objects = InheritanceManager()

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        raise AttributeError('Attribute {} not found on item {}'.format(name, self.name))


class ItemA(Item):
    attribute_a = models.CharField(max_length=10)


class ItemB(Item):
    attribute_b = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

A test:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Initialize Django Environment
    import os, sys
    sys.path.append('C:/Data/Code/quicktest/testproject')
    os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'testproject.settings'
    import django
    django.setup()

from testapp.models import Item

for item in Item.objects.all().select_subclasses():
    print(item.name)
```

The result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Data/Code/quicktest/testproject/testapp/tests.py", line 11, in <module>
    for item in Item.objects.all().select_subclasses():
  File "C:\Data\Code\quicktest\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 274, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "C:\Data\Code\quicktest\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1242, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "C:\Data\Code\quicktest\venv\lib\site-packages\model_utils\managers.py", line 28, in __iter__
    sub_obj = queryset._get_sub_obj_recurse(obj, s)
  File "C:\Data\Code\quicktest\venv\lib\site-packages\model_utils\managers.py", line 211, in _get_sub_obj_recurse
    node = getattr(obj, rel)
  File "C:\Data\Code\quicktest\testproject\testapp\models.py", line 12, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError('Attribute {} not found on item {}'.format(name, self.name))
AttributeError: Attribute itema not found on item some itemb
```

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: Your `__getattr__` method doesn't do anything but raise an exception when trying to access any attributes of `Item` instances, I'm not sure I see the point in it?

Comment: There is obviously more to my getattr function but i don’t believe it is relevant to the issue.  The point is that getattr gets called and when the attribute it is called with is not of interest you are supposed to raise AttributeError.

Comment: All instances of `Item` are going to have an attribute `itema` because of the implicit one to one relationship created by Django when you subclass a model and your `__getattr__` method raises an exception when this attribute is accessed - that is the issue. I have no idea why you are overriding this method

Comment: That is not true.  The getattr is only called as a last resort when the attribute is not found by regular means.  This is your chance to add special dynamic access of various attributes.  Whatever you choose to not handle is when you raise AttributeError

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that is working. Not sure I am excited about it though.

```
def __getattr__(self, name):

    # Do magical stuff that getattr is intended for


    # Catch if the reason this was called was because its a reverse one to one that doesn't exist
    try:
        model_field = self.__class__._meta.get_field(name)
        if isinstance(model_field, models.fields.reverse_related.OneToOneRel):
            return None
    except models.fields.FieldDoesNotExist:
        pass

    raise AttributeError('Attribute {} not found on item {}'.format(name, self.name))
```

I feel like the InheritanceManager should accept an AttributeError exception, but this works